# Disable a button in html or html and typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic4

I am trying to disable a button by pressing it without any condition but I can not. Is a Ionic-Angular project.

**My html:**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <button ion-button #a (click)="letraIntroducida('a')">a</button>
</ion-content>
```

**My ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-tipopregunta1',
  templateUrl: 'tipopregunta1.html',
})
export class Tipopregunta1Page {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  letraIntroducida(letraUsuario: string){
  //here makes code not important
  }

}
```

I only want to disable the button after clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the button as disabled with a property

.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <button 
      ion-button 
      #a 
      [disabled]="isDisabled" // <- set disabled prop here
      (click)="letraIntroducida('a')">a
    </button>
</ion-content>
```

.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tipopregunta1',
  templateUrl: 'tipopregunta1.html',
})
export class Tipopregunta1Page {
  isDisabled = false; // <- create variable to determine state

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

  letraIntroducida(letraUsuario: string){
    isDisabled = true; // <- toggle the state
  }
}
```

Also, welcome to SO.  Next time, include some of the steps you tried to make it work and why those failed.

The community is much more open when people show that they tried to solve the problems by themself first.

Comment: Oohhhh, thks. Next time I will give more details

Comment: If you had many buttons, just name them independently such as `isSubmitDisabled` and `isCancelDisabled`